# How to iterate over <class 'tarfile.TarFile'>

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, tarfile

I am trying to figure out a way to iterate over multiples files which are inside the tarfile. Tarfile class have two object and and both objects have multiple files inside of it. I want to iterate over each file and do some operation but I am not able to do so. I am able to iterate over class objects but not over files.

```
for file in filter_file_name:
        tar_file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='abc-logs',Key=file)
        tar_content = tar_file_obj['Body'].read()
        with tarfile.open(fileobj = io.BytesIO(tar_content)) as tar:
            print(tar)
```

After that I am getting output as:

```
<tarfile.TarFile object at 0x7ff9d35d8eb8>
<tarfile.TarFile object at 0x7ff9d35afc50>
```

Now above two objects have multiple files and I want to iterate over each files and perform some operation. Below is sample output files.

```
<TarInfo './/logs/0005B95205BA/abc_logs/PERFORMANCE' at 0x7fc498a13f20> 
<TarInfo './/logs/0005B95205BA/abc_logs/PER/20200817120325.txt' at 0x7fc497fb2110>
<TarInfo './/logs/0005B95205BA/abc_logs/PER/20200817120325.txt' at 0x7fc497fb21d8>
<TarInfo './/logs/0005B95205BA/abc_logs/PER/20200817120325.txt' at 0x7fc497fb22a0>
<TarInfo './/logs/0005B95205BA/abc_logs/PER/20200817120325.txt' at 0x7fc497fb2368>
```

Comment: What's the question? You can literally just iterate over the tarfile object (aka `for entry in tar`), or call `getmembers()`, or repeatedly call `tarfile.next()`.